# How can I access intl.formatMessage() in mobx store in reactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, react-intl

I have two JSON files with names **'en.json'** and **'fr.json'** which has all the translations.

**en.json**

`{ "General.LearnMore": "Learn More" }`

I have a mobx store (.ts file) and I want to access `intl.formatMessage()` in that class.

It is easier in functional components. I can use `useIntl()` hook but how can I do the same in a store file (non-component).

When I write the below code in store file:

```
const messages = defineMessages({
  SMS: {
    id: 'General.LearnMore',
  },
});

const cache = createIntlCache();
const locale = localStorage.getItem('locale')!;
const intl = createIntl({ locale, messages: {} }, cache);
console.log(intl.formatMessage({ id: 'General.select' }));
console.log(intl.formatMessage({ id: messages.sms.id }));
```

**It gives this error:**

[image]

**What I am missing and How can I fix this? Please help!**

Answer (score 0):

In `createIntl` you pass an empty object to `messages` so `intl` doesn't find the ids.

To fix, import the en.json:

```
import enMessages from '../path/to/en.json'
```

and pass it on `cretaeIntl`:

```
const intl = createIntl({ locale, messages: enMessages }, cache);
```

If you created the messages object with `defineMessages` just for the purpose of getting value from `intl` - you can delete it, it doesn't give access to the key-value files (`createIntl` doesn't automatically get the data of `intlProvider`, it needs full initialition with `locale` and `messages`)

If you want the messages to be updated every time the locale is switched so [here a good example](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/issues/243#issuecomment-522771872)

Hope this will help!